# Mysql syntax error 1064 using if statements

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am attempting to run the following query:

```
 (IF(book.book_type_id = "1", IF(inventory.cost < (follette_title.usedbuyingprice *1.37), follette_title.usedbuyingprice*1.37)), inventory.cost) AS Cost,
```

which is trying to see if the book type is 1 then check to see if the cost is less than the follette used buying price * 1.37, if it is then set the price at follette used buying price * 1.37, if not then the cost is Cost.
I keep getting this error:

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')), inventory.cost) AS Cost,
        (concat(IFNULL(buyer_type.buyer_type, ""),IFNUL' at line 11
```

and I am not sure why.  The manual does not give a clear reason for this, and I have many lines before this one that are similar with no errors in them.
Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: You're quoting as if the strings are objects. What happens if you replace `"` with `'`? Also, have you considered using a `case` statement for this; your code isn't very clear and a case might make it easier to read.

Comment: Using a `case` will make the code more readable and clear. Agree.

Comment: @Ben didn't change anything if I go with ' instead of ".  I did not use a case statement since for this line I just need to see if the book type is 1 or else the if statement does not need to execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a misplaced ')'

What you need is

```
(IF(book_type.book_type_id = "1", IF(inventory.cost < follette_title.usedbuying_price *1.37, follette_title.usedbuying_price*1.37, ""), inventory.cost)) AS Cost
```

instead of

```
(IF(book.book_type_id = "1", IF(inventory.cost < (follette_title.usedbuyingprice *1.37), follette_title.usedbuyingprice*1.37)), inventory.cost) AS Cost,
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and i am still getting the same error.

Comment: On closely inspecting the the inner `IF` construct, I found that it does not have the third component which is mandatory. `IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)` is the syntax. In your case the inner 'IF' is `IF(inventory.cost < (follette_title.usedbuyingprice *1.37), follette_title.usedbuyingprice*1.37)`. The 3rd component is absent.

Comment: Also could you please insert your whole query above? Looking at the error you get, I suppose some other constituent of your query is also failing.

Comment: when I added a third expression of "" the error was resolved. The query now is: (IF(book_type.book_type_id = "1", IF(inventory.cost < follette_title.usedbuying_price *1.37, follette_title.usedbuying_price*1.37, ""), inventory.cost)) AS Cost,  If you adjust your answer to reflect your comment, I would be happy to mark as the correct answer.

Comment: Ok. updated. Thanks. More than the points, I'm glad I could help you find a way out of your predicament :)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I will try to pay it forward when I can help out someone else.